# UnityEngine.Component does not contain definition...C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My machine at home and university one have different versions of Unity installed. Newer at my home and older at university and I wonder if that's what caused my problem. Game worked fine until I tried to further develop it on my home computer.

Get two error messages:

`'UnityEngine.Component' does not contain a definition for 'bounds' and no extension method 'bounds' of type 'UnityEngine.Component' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?`

And:

`'UnityEngine.Component' does not contain a definition for 'MovePosition' and no extension method 'MovePosition' of type 'UnityEngine.Component' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?`

Here's my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SantaBagController : MonoBehaviour {

    public Camera cam;

    private float maxWidth;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        if (cam == null) {
            cam = Camera.main;
        }
        Vector3 upperCorner = new Vector3 (Screen.width, Screen.height, 0.0f);
        Vector3 targetWidth = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint (upperCorner);
        float SantaBagWidth = renderer.bounds.extents.x;
        maxWidth = targetWidth.x - SantaBagWidth;
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () {
            Vector3 rawPosition = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
            Vector3 targetPosition = new Vector3 (rawPosition.x, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            float targetWidth = Mathf.Clamp (targetPosition.x, -maxWidth, maxWidth);
            targetPosition = new Vector3 (targetWidth, targetPosition.y, targetPosition.z);
            rigidbody2D.MovePosition (targetPosition);      
    }
}
```

Please help! Many thanks!

Comment: To be 100% sure your project will work with older and newer versions of Unity i would recommend to create some local members for components like `Rigidbody2D meRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>()` this will ensure that you're using correct `Component` type.

Comment: Where do you get `rigidbody2D` variable, which type is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can no longer access components that are attached to the GameObject directly like you could in the past. You **must** now use `GetComponent`. Your code is valid with Unity 4 and below but not with 5.

These are the errors:

```
rigidbody2D.MovePosition(targetPosition);
```

and

```
float SantaBagWidth = renderer.bounds.extents.x;
```

To fix it, declare `rigidbody2D` with `Rigidbody2D rigidbody2D;`.

then use GetComponent to get the renderer with `GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.extents.x;`

The whole code:

```
public Camera cam;

private float maxWidth;

Rigidbody2D rigidbody2D;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    if (cam == null)
    {
        cam = Camera.main;
    }
    Vector3 upperCorner = new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, 0.0f);
    Vector3 targetWidth = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(upperCorner);
    float SantaBagWidth = GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.extents.x;
    maxWidth = targetWidth.x - SantaBagWidth;
}


// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector3 rawPosition = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    Vector3 targetPosition = new Vector3(rawPosition.x, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    float targetWidth = Mathf.Clamp(targetPosition.x, -maxWidth, maxWidth);
    targetPosition = new Vector3(targetWidth, targetPosition.y, targetPosition.z);
    rigidbody2D.MovePosition(targetPosition);
}
```

Comment: Note that with some 5.x versions, using a variable with the same naming as the old reference triggers a stupid warning. So using rigidbody2D may say that it hides a reference with the same name. Though it does not...

Comment: Yes, that's right. Those were early Unity version. They are long gone and I assume OP is using at-least 5.3 or above version. If that's not the case then OP will see your comment. I also do believe that this happens **only** when you import old project in 5.x version then click yes when Unity asks you if it should use old API or something similar.

Comment: @Everts That's why you have `#pragma warning disable` and `#pragma warning restore`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the "MonoBehaviour properties " (such as transform, renderer, ... are depreciated.

Instead, use the explicit function `GetComponent`

```
    Renderer r = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    if( r != null )
    {
          float santaBagWidth = r.bounds.extents.x;
          maxWidth = targetWidth.x - santaBagWidth ;
    }
```

The same advice for your rigidbody. Cache it in the Awake function and use it in the Fixed Update

```
private Rigidbody2D r2D ;

void Awake()
{
    r2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>() ;
    if( r2D == null )
         r2D = gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void FixedUpdate () {
   Vector3 rawPosition = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
   Vector3 targetPosition = new Vector3 (rawPosition.x, 0.0f, 0.0f);
   float targetWidth = Mathf.Clamp (targetPosition.x, -maxWidth, maxWidth);
   targetPosition = new Vector3 (targetWidth, targetPosition.y, targetPosition.z);
    r2D.MovePosition (targetPosition);      
}
```